# AWS CDK: No Container Instances were found in your capacity provider error with EC2 + PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I am trying to create an AWS backend infrastructure using CDK. My setup is as follows:

I have a single instance postgresql database in ec2 that is accessed by an API service that is containerized (also in ec2). An application load balancer routes the requests to the service containers. The service containers are part of an auto-scaling-group.

The postgresql db is in a private subnet and the ASG is in the public subnet.

The postgresql db deploys fine and starts ok.
The service containers are failing to deploy. I get a cryptic error stating that "No Container Instances were found in your capacity provider"

The background is that the service container ASG was rearchitected from a single SQLite which deployed successfully previously. I added the postgresql db and the service scaling using ASG (I tested the SQLite version with the ASG and that deploys).

What could be the reason?
It would be great if the response could include the correct CDK construct for this setup.